# Write dataframe to SQL dedicated database using Synapse Analytics

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-synapse

I would like to load a dataframe from my Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 and write it to an SQL
dedicated database that I created in Synapse.

This is what I did:

```
df = spark.read.format("delta").load(BronzePath)
df.write.format("com.databricks.spark.sqldw").option("url", jdbcUrl).save()
```

And I have the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: com.databricks.spark.sqldw.
```

Doing:

```
df.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("MyTable")
```

creates the table in Spark default database (blue cross). That is not what I need. I want to have my table in the dedicated database (blue arrow):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Post more of your code including jdbc url, if it's different than [this guide](https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/azure/synapse-analytics.html#usage-batch-1). I don't see the code to set the storage key in conf and you seem to be using different way to save as well.

```
# Otherwise, set up the Blob storage account access key in the notebook session conf.
spark.conf.set(
  "fs.azure.account.key.<your-storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net",
  "<your-storage-account-access-key>")

# Get some data from an Azure Synapse table.
df = spark.read \
  .format("com.databricks.spark.sqldw") \
  .option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://<the-rest-of-the-connection-string>") \
  .option("tempDir", "wasbs://<your-container-name>@<your-storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<your-directory-name>") \
  .option("forwardSparkAzureStorageCredentials", "true") \
  .option("dbTable", "<your-table-name>") \
  .load()

# Load data from an Azure Synapse query.
df = spark.read \
  .format("com.databricks.spark.sqldw") \
  .option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://<the-rest-of-the-connection-string>") \
  .option("tempDir", "wasbs://<your-container-name>@<your-storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<your-directory-name>") \
  .option("forwardSparkAzureStorageCredentials", "true") \
  .option("query", "select x, count(*) as cnt from table group by x") \
  .load()

# Apply some transformations to the data, then use the
# Data Source API to write the data back to another table in Azure Synapse.

df.write \
  .format("com.databricks.spark.sqldw") \
  .option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://<the-rest-of-the-connection-string>") \
  .option("forwardSparkAzureStorageCredentials", "true") \
  .option("dbTable", "<your-table-name>") \
  .option("tempDir", "wasbs://<your-container-name>@<your-storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<your-directory-name>") \
  .save()
```

Also read

- [Supported save modes for batch writes](https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/azure/synapse-analytics.html#supported-save-modes-for-batch-writes) and
- [Write semantics](https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/azure/synapse-analytics.html#write-semantics)
  in FAQ.

---

> creates the table in Spark default database (blue cross). That is not what I need. I want to have my table in the dedicated database (blue arrow):

As described [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-load-save-functions.html#saving-to-persistent-tables) *"Spark will create a default local Hive metastore (using Derby) for you."*

So when you don't give it a path/jdbcurl (`df.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("MyTable")`), it'll save to local Hive.