# PySpark Equivalent of synapsesql in ASA

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-synapse

When working with a Spark notebook for Azure Synapse Analytics (ASA), I can use Scala to save a CSV file as a table in a Dedicated SQL Pool with two simple statements:

```scala
%%spark
// [1] - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-load-save-functions.html
// [2] - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-introduction-abfs-uri
val testDF = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load(
    "abfss://earytestfs@earytestsa.dfs.core.windows.net/TIOBE-azure-backup.csv"
);
// [3] - https://www.aizoo.info/post/dropping-a-sql-table-in-your-synapse-spark-notebooks
// [4] - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67907984/write-data-to-sql-dw-from-apache-spark-in-azure-synapse
testDF.write.mode("overwrite").synapsesql("eary_dedicated_test_sql_pool.dbo.TIOBE_test");
```

Unfortunately, [3] from above seems to imply the synapsesql function does not exist for PySpark. Has this situation changed since Darren last updated his post?

*NOTE: I do not want to mess with configurating the Azure Synapse Dedicated SQL Pool Connector for Apache Spark. My dedicated SQL pool is in the same workspace as my Spark Pool so I don't feel like I should have to hassle with configuring a bunch of authentication options:* 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/synapse-spark-sql-pool-import-export?tabs=scala%2Cscala1%2Cscala2%2Cscala3%2Cscala4%2Cscala5

**EDIT**: The following pyspark code gives me 
**"AttributeError: 'DataFrameWriter' object has no attribute 'synapsesql'
"**
on Line 7

```py
%%pyspark
df = spark.read.load('abfss://earytestfs@earytestsa.dfs.core.windows.net/TIOBE-azure-backup.csv', format='csv'
## If header exists uncomment line below
, header=True
)

# [5] - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69720753/write-dataframe-to-sql-dedicated-database-using-synapse-analytics
df.write.mode("overwrite").synapsesql("eary_dedicated_test_sql_pool.dbo.TIOBE_test")
```

Comment: synapsesql Does work in Python now.  Are you getting a specific error?

Comment: @wBob - I edited the question to add the error I get when I try to call the synapsesql function from PySpark. Maybe I'm doing it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python support for `synapsesql` has been here for about a year now.  Just add the imports as per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/synapse-spark-sql-pool-import-export):

```
# Add required imports
import com.microsoft.spark.sqlanalytics
from com.microsoft.spark.sqlanalytics.Constants import Constants
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

# Get the table with synapsesql method and expose as temp view
df = spark.read.synapsesql("sandpit_ded.dbo.nation")

df.createOrReplaceTempView("vw_nation")
```

[Python Notebook using synapsesql method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7x8h.png)